# finding cell coordinates between two points in meshgrid using python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a `meshgrid` defined as:

```
from numpy import *    
x = arange(0,1107,1)    
y = arange(0,1129,1)    
xx,yy = meshgrid(x,y)
```

I am trying to get the coordinates of cells lying between any two end cells. For eg, coordinates of all cells lying between `(435, 550)` and `(987, 980)` when these two points are joined by a straight line. So basically its finding the cell coordinates, through which the straight line passes. Any help would be nice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please first try something and then tell us what you tried by [edit]ing the question and also precisely mention what went wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are trying to solve is equivalent to drawing a line in an 2d array of pixels.

Have a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_drawing_algorithm and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm

You will have to precisely define what you mean by "between", ie a cell (x,y) is included if the line between xstart,ystart and xend,yend intersects the rectangle (x,y,x+1,y+1).  (Or: do you want the line to be at xstart+0.5,ystart+0.5 etc?)

Comment: I got the idea with line drawing algorithm. Basically I chose a pixel and increased x coordinate by 0.5 and y according to straight line equation: slope*(x-x1)+y1, slope being calculated using two point formula. I wrote a code finally to check if there were repeated or missing pixels visually and tallied few with image, it was good. Thanks to you.